What kind of updates are performed here?
My Ubuntu installation prompted me to do some OS updates in the software center and to restart afterwards. What kind of updates are these and where can I see what changed? How is this different than using the GUI for apt?


It's installing the same updates as with sudo apt upgrade, but possibly also upgrading some snap packages.
To see which deb packages was installed, see the apt log:
cat /var/log/apt/history.log

To see the snap log, you could use:
journalctl -u snapd

Or:
grep snapd /var/log/syslog

There might be a more specific search criteria to filter the snap log for installed packages (I'll revise when I know what exactly to filter out).
